# make recursive CTE Query with clause

Tags: sql-server

Data of mytable

```
   ID_element Element1 Element2 DATE_Ele ID_Personne
        1       NULL     25      2002      1
        2       46     NULL      2003      1
        3       2      NULL      2004      1
        4       3       NULL     2005      1
        5       5      NULL      2006      1
        6      178      NULL    2007       1
```

Salary 
DATA of table Salary

```
ID_Personne       Date
1                  2007
```

as you see here in this example first we get the date mactches between the two table , in our case , it is 2007 then we increment this Date until Element1 is not null and element2 is null but i prefer to stop the incrementation when this condition is not verified , as you see in this data , the year 2002 does not respect our condition so we stop the loop at this step .

### this is my data

```
set dateformat 'ymd'
Drop table #salary
CREATE TABLE #salary(
    ID_Personne int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
    DATE_Per Date
)



--This is the data of my table:
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2015-05-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2019-05-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2017-02-18')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2019-10-05')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2010-08-25')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-08-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2004-09-13')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2005-04-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-02-14')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2014-05-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2019-12-12')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-08-13')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2011-01-18')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2009-09-19')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2005-05-19')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2008-04-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-02-14')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-05-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-12-12')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2017-08-13')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2013-08-05')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2009-07-25')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2005-05-19')



Drop table #myTable
CREATE TABLE #myTable(
    ID_element int IDENTITY(200,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
    Element1 nvarchar(10),
    Element2 nvarchar(10),
    DATE_Ele Date,
    ID_Personne int
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Personne)
    REFERENCES #salary (ID_Personne)

)

INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2011-01-18',1)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2009-09-19',2)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2005-05-19',3)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2008-04-10',4)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2018-02-14',5)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2018-05-10',6)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2018-12-12',7)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2004-03-20',8)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2018-02-14',9)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2014-02-14',9)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2015-02-14',9)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2013-02-14',9)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2014-05-10',10)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2019-12-12',11)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2019-10-05',4)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2010-08-25',5)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2009-08-25',5)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2008-08-25',5)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2007-03-25',5)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2018-08-10',6)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2004-09-13',7)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2005-04-10',8)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2009-07-25',10)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2005-05-19',11)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2004-05-19',11)




Drop table #cteReports15
;WITH
  cteReports (ID_Personne, Annee)
  AS
  (
    SELECT t.ID_Personne, Year(t.DATE_Per) as Annee 
    FROM #salary as t
    Inner Join #myTable  as a
    ON t.ID_Personne=a.ID_Personne
    AND t.DATE_Per=a.DATE_Ele
    where a.Element1 is not null AND a.Element2 is null

    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.ID_Personne, Year(t.DATE_Per)-1 as Anneef 
   FROM #salary as t
    Inner Join #myTable  as a
    ON t.ID_Personne=a.ID_Personne
    AND t.DATE_Per=a.DATE_Ele
    Inner Join cteReports
    on cteReports.ID_Personne=a.ID_Personne

  )
  --Drop table #cteReports11
  Select Distinct ID_Personne, Annee 
INTO        #cteReports15
FROM        cteReports
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```

Comment: expected output seems bit odd,can you format that

Comment: Can you explain the output? Your explanation is not at all clear what you want. And I can't make heads or tails of it from the desired output you posted. This looks a LOT like the question you asked yesterday which I can't seem to find now.

Comment: Hi Sean Lange , i explained as possible as i can the ouput . please could u check that .  thanks for your time

Comment: Yeah that isn't any clearer to me. There is no loop here. I suspect this isn't too hard to code but unless I can understand the rules I am not really able to help.

Comment: the loop i am talking about is the CTE_Query above , i posted the code also . AnyWays thanks for ur help . i want to make CTE query on the date (-1)  until the value of the element1 is not null . if a value is null , so i stop the query

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear on your requirement.

However based on the result you've provided below query will help you perhaps;

**Execute the following and check**

```
set dateformat 'ymd'
Drop table #salary
CREATE TABLE #salary(
    ID_Personne int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
    DATE_Per Date
)



--This is the data of your table:
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2015-05-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2019-05-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2017-02-18')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2019-10-05')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2010-08-25')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-08-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2004-09-13')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2005-04-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-02-14')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2014-05-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2019-12-12')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-08-13')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2011-01-18')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2009-09-19')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2005-05-19')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2008-04-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-02-14')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-05-10')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2018-12-12')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2017-08-13')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2013-08-05')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2009-07-25')
INSERT INTO #salary VALUES ('2005-05-19')



Drop table #myTable
CREATE TABLE #myTable(
    ID_element int IDENTITY(200,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
    Element1 nvarchar(10),
    Element2 nvarchar(10),
    DATE_Ele Date,
    ID_Personne int
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Personne)
    REFERENCES #salary (ID_Personne)

)

INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2011-01-18',1)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2009-09-19',2)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2005-05-19',3)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2008-04-10',4)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2018-02-14',5)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2018-05-10',6)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2018-12-12',7)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2004-03-20',8)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2018-02-14',9)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2014-02-14',9)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2015-02-14',9)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2013-02-14',9)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2014-05-10',10)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2019-12-12',11)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2019-10-05',4)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2010-08-25',5)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2009-08-25',5)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2008-08-25',5)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2007-03-25',5)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2018-08-10',6)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2004-09-13',7)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2005-04-10',8)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2009-07-25',10)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A',NULL,'2005-05-19',11)
INSERT INTO #myTable VALUES ('A','B','2004-05-19',11)
--end of your data insertions


--Query to perform the required result starts
DECLARE @RequiredData TABLE
(
 PersonID INT,
 SalaryYear INT,
Element1 nvarchar(10),
Element2 nvarchar(10)
)
DECLARE @PersonID as INT
DECLARE @SalaryDate DATE
DECLARE @yearcursor CURSOR 

SET @yearcursor =CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT  ID_Personne,DATE_Per
   FROM  #salary  


OPEN @yearcursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM @yearcursor INTO @PersonID,@SalaryDate

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN


IF EXISTS (SELECT ID_Personne,Year(DATE_Ele) SalryYear,Element1 ,Element2
 FROM  #myTable M
WHERE @PersonID=M.ID_Personne AND @SalaryDate=M.DATE_Ele
AND  Element1 IS NOT NULL AND Element2 IS NULL)
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RequiredData
        SELECT DISTINCT ID_Personne,Year(DATE_Ele) SalryYear,Element1 ,Element2
        FROM  #myTable M
        WHERE @PersonID=M.ID_Personne 
        AND  Element1 IS NOT NULL AND Element2 IS NULL AND  M.DATE_Ele=@SalaryDate
DECLARE @incrementerDate INT=Year(@SalaryDate)-1
DECLARE @IsValid BIT=1
DECLARE @MinYear INT= (SELECT MIN(YEAR(DATE_Ele)) FROM #myTable M WHERE @PersonID=M.ID_Personne AND Element1 IS NOT NULL AND Element2 IS NULL )


WHILE(@IsValid=1 AND @MinYear<=@incrementerDate)
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID_Personne,@incrementerDate SalryYear,Element1 ,Element2
 FROM  #myTable M
WHERE @PersonID=M.ID_Personne AND @incrementerDate=YEAR(M.DATE_Ele)
AND  Element1 IS NOT NULL AND Element2 IS NULL)

BEGIN
INSERT INTO @RequiredData
    SELECT ID_Personne,Year(DATE_Ele) SalryYear,Element1 ,Element2
    FROM  #myTable M
        WHERE @PersonID=M.ID_Personne 
        AND  Element1 IS NOT NULL AND Element2 IS NULL 
        AND  YEAR(M.DATE_Ele)=@incrementerDate
SET @incrementerDate=@incrementerDate-1
END

ELSE IF  EXISTS (SELECT ID_Personne,@incrementerDate SalryYear,Element1 ,Element2
 FROM  #myTable M
WHERE @PersonID=M.ID_Personne AND @incrementerDate=YEAR(M.DATE_Ele)
AND  Element1 IS NULL AND Element2 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @IsValid=0
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @incrementerDate=@incrementerDate-1
END
END
END


 FETCH NEXT FROM @yearcursor INTO  @PersonID,@SalaryDate
END

CLOSE @yearcursor
DEALLOCATE @yearcursor


SELECT * FROM @RequiredData ORDER BY PersonID,SalaryYear DESC

 There;
```

- I have removed the common table extension and introduce a cursor
- The cursor will repeatedly check the matched data set for given person ID and date
- If it is matched then check the past years of the given user where Element1 is not null and Element 2 is null and insert them to the temporary table
- This will be repeated until an iteration violates the condition
- Get the required output from temporary table @RequiredData

Comment: thanks for your reply , we have to soustract one year from the salary date during the curson and display that date and how could i add if i want to that the cursor stop , next record which the element1 is null and the element2 is not null . thanks for your help

Comment: You meant if the immediate previous year's element1 is null and element2 is not null you want to stop the recursion for that person ID?

Comment: i mean soustract one year from the salaryDate during the loop for everyID Person as long as the element1 is not null and element is null . we must stop the incrementation when element1 has not a value and element2 has a value.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Execute the query and see whether that is the output you want.

Comment: really apprecitate your reply , it is nearly what i want . i have edited the requirement , could u please check it . thanks a lot

Comment: That's what the above query gives. Check the results.  For example ID 9 The matching year is 2018 and we subtract one its 2017. Though there  are matching entries for 2015 since no matching data for 2017 we break the loop and check for next id.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but i saw also another probleme , the incrementation on the salaryDate does not work , it must increment this date as long as the criteria is respected .  for example The ID 9 , the loop must stop in 2013 . thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127335/discussion-between-buddhi-madarasinghe-and-ilyas).